# synchronous vs asynchronous write/delete in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax

What is the difference in synchronous and asynchronous write/delete in Cassandra  ?

If I use `executeAsynchronously()` instead of `execute()` method of `CqlOperation` class (datastax driver) will it improve the performance in terms of throughput (TPS) ? In my application I am doing single insert/delete as well as batch insert.
Till now i was using only `execute` method (synchronous)  and I am thinking to use asynchronous execute to improve the performance of application in terms of TPS.

Comment: Before reading batches, read up on them. Batches do not improve performance

Answer (score 2):

Async writes offer better performance per worker but it adds overhead of callbacks and error handling.

I have done a test recently to find performance benefits as well as callback implementation with error handling using a single worker with 1M records written Async was found 4 Times as fast as Synchronous ones. `in_flight queries` were limited to 1000, this number can be tuned accordingly as per environment conditions (Number of connections you want to put on the wire, say with 200ms network latency and 1ms server response time one may go for 200 queries to be put in_flight, while Sync call would have let server free for 199ms out of 200ms in this case server would be processing atleast one query almost all the time) but without restriction it will congest network with possible degradation in performance.

In some cases Synchronous query may be more suitable, especially if the result of the query is critical before moving ahead with program. But in most of the cases Async suffices.

In short the answer to your question is Yes - I have tested **TPS increase of 4x**.

Reference - [performance evaluation using async writes](http://bhuvanrawal.me/cassandra/optimisation/performance/cassandra-async-vs-sync-writes-performance-evaluation)

Answer (score 1):

sync write(or delete) to cassandra will block code execution until the client receives a confirmation that the operation has been completed based on the consistency level.

On the other hand, async write(or delete) will send the query to cassandra, and then proceed with the code execution(will not block). Now you have to register some kind of callback that will inform you(asynchronously) that the write operation has completed.

All of the blocking adds up, and can slow down your application. Because async queries immediately proceed, they allow you send more async queries right after instead of waiting on the first one to finish. This is where the performance increase occurs, especially if you are sending a lot of queries to cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely increase the performance.
I have not tried it but link below says the same
[Read the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667228/async-writes-seem-to-be-broken-in-cassandra/27895175#27895175)

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries