# Cassandra loses data on multiple async writes to the same partition

Tags: java, asynchronous, cassandra, datastax

I am using Cassandra 2.1.14 with Datastax Java driver (2.1.10.2/3.0.2). Cassandra is currently running on one test server. Everything works fine except asynchronous writes to the same partition. Here is my code snippet:

```
PreparedStatement insertId = session.prepare("INSERT INTO " + KEYSPACE + "." + ID_TABLE +
            " (" +
            PARTITION + ", " + INDEX + ", " + ID +
            ") " +
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?) USING TTL ?").setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ONE);

BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(insertId);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (ASYNC_WRITE) {
        ResultSetFuture resultSetFuture = session.executeAsync(boundStatement.bind(partition, i, list.get(i), TTL_SECONDS));

        Futures.addCallback(resultSetFuture, new FutureCallback<ResultSet>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                Logger.Log.error("Exception: " + Logger.getStackTraceString(e));
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ResultSet results) {
                Logger.Log.debug("OK");
            }
        });
    } else {
        session.execute(boundStatement.bind(partition, i, list.get(i), TTL_SECONDS);
    }
}
```

For a list with 3 elements and asynchronous writes only two elements are written, e.g., 0 and 2 or 1 and 2. No exceptions are thrown and onSuccess() is called for all writes. Thereby, there is absolutely no load on the server as mentiond here: [Async writes seem to be broken in Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667228/async-writes-seem-to-be-broken-in-cassandra). When I switch to synchronous write all elements are written.

**Update**
I have found a solution. It looks like a new BoundStatement must be created every time before calling executeAsync:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(insertId);
    if (ASYNC_WRITE) {
        ResultSetFuture resultSetFuture = session.executeAsync(boundStatement.bind(partition, i, list.get(i), TTL_SECONDS));

        Futures.addCallback(resultSetFuture, new FutureCallback<ResultSet>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                Logger.Log.error("Exception: " + Logger.getStackTraceString(e));
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ResultSet results) {
                Logger.Log.debug("OK");
            }
        });
    } else {
        session.execute(boundStatement.bind(partition, i, list.get(i), TTL_SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something missing in your code in the if(ASYNC_WRITE) condition block?   The future returned from session.executeAsync has no name.  Also I'm guessing you are using Futures.addCallback?  I see FutureCallback methods (onFailure, onSuccess) but no declaration of an implementation.

Comment: How are you reading the data back?  I see that you are likely adding a future callback, to log when the write happens, but I don't see where/when data is read back.

Comment: @AndyTolbert I added the missing line. I am only writing here. For reading, I used Datastax DevCenter.

Comment: Yes BoundStatements are not thread safe, see JAVA-1198 (https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1198)